# How do I convert Data to signed Int?

Tags: swift, kotlin, type-conversion, integer, unsigned-integer

I'm in an iOS project where we convert incoming `Data` to a `byteArray`. It looks something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let data: Data? = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let data = data else { return }

        [UInt8](data).forEach { print("--Doing stuff here", $0) }
    }
}
```

Now, there's a similar project in `Android studio` using `Kotlin` that also converts `Data` to a `byteArray`. BUT it turns out that `ByteArray` in `Kotlin` is `signed` not `unsigned` (I'm guessing Int8).

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-byte/

> > Represents a 8-bit signed integer.

To me this doesn't make any sense. In my world a `byteArray` is an `array` of `uInt8`. But perhaps I don't know this stuff well enough... care to explain anyone?

Anyway, the issue is that we need to take negative numbers. Obviously this works with `Kotlin´s` `signed` `Int` but not with `iOS` since `uInt8` can't store negative numbers.

So, how do I convert `Data` to `Int8`? I tried like this:

```
[Int8](data).forEach { print("--Doing stuff here", $0) }
```

But I get an error saying `No exact matches in call to initializer`

So how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing the conversion tested on [Online Swift Playground](https://online.swiftplayground.run/):

```
let data = Data([1, 50, 215, 255]) 
var bytes: [Int8] = data.map { Int8(bitPattern: $0) }
print(bytes) // [1, 50, -41, -1]
```

Comment: That's nice, thanks!